# How can I "source" expect script

Tags: shell-script, shell, environment-variables, expect

I'm forced to use a script like below:

```sh
# test.sh
function my_fun
{
    echo "Give value for FOO"
    local my_var
    read my_var
    export FOO=$my_var
}

# Call my_fun function
my_fun
```

by sourcing it from my shell.

```sh
$ source test.sh
Give value for FOO
stackexchange
$ echo $FOO
stackexchange
```

I would like to automate the script with expect like shown below:

```sh
$ expect test.exp
$ echo $FOO
stackexchange
```

The amount and names of the environmental variables in `test.sh` is unknown.

**Update:**

- Added my_fun functionc all to test.sh.

Comment: How will your expect script know when to stop? Do you need to parse the test.sh script with expect?

Comment: if the number of variables is unknown, how do you know what answers to put in the expect script?

Comment: The questions are known but the resulting environmental variables are not. This is also how the expect script knows when to stop waiting for more input.

Comment: Consider, separately, sending the input to the function (which I didn't see you calling, above): `my_fun <<< something$'\n'"something else"`

Comment: Possible, but I'm trying to avoid this because I think expect is more readable.

Comment: I can't see anywhere that `my_fun` is being called, so I'm not sure what you're doing.  If `my_fun` is called within `test.sh`, then why not just `source test.sh <<<'stackexchange'`?

Comment: Using `expect` rather than a simple redirection is not making "more readable".

Comment: If the amount of question (unknown) is more than 1, you will end up with lot of listed arguments with no explanation. For example, `source test.sh <<<"1\ndefault\n4\n6\noptionX\n2\nyes\nno\nyes\n"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fundamental problem is that a child process cannot alter the environment of its parent. This is why you need to `source` that shell script, so the environment variables will persist in your current shell.

Expect is designed to `spawn` child processes. Your current shell *cannot* be affected by the result of `expect test.exp`.

However, you can spawn a shell, source that shell script, and then keep *that* shell around by interacting with it: this is off the top of my head and is untested:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set timeout -1
spawn $env(SHELL)
set myprompt "some pattern that matches your prompt"
expect -re $myprompt
send "source test.sh\r"
expect {
    "Give value for " {
        # provide the same answer for every question:
        send "some value\r"
        exp_continue
    }
    -re $myprompt
}
interact
```

Now you are interacting with the shell you spawned. When you `exit` that shell, the spawned shell dies, then expect script ends, and you are back in your current shell (without the variables you initialized).

Comment: Good idea, I think I can spawn extra shell and work on there in the expect.

Comment: @Jaakko Note that this won't set `FOO` in the original shell, even if `my_fun` _is_ called somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a create a shell script that diffs the environments from before and after running that function:

```
#!/bin/bash
# run.sh
source ./test.sh
ENV_BEFORE=$(set | grep -v "^_")
my_fun
ENV_AFTER=$(set | grep -v "^ENV_BEFORE" | grep -v "^_")
# echo the new environment variables
echo "$ENV_AFTER" | grep -v -F -x -f <(echo "$ENV_BEFORE")
```

Then run that script using expect:

```
# test.exp
log_user 0
spawn ./run.sh
expect "Give value for "
expect -re  "(.*)\r\n"
send -- "stackexchange\r\n"
expect -re  "(.*)\r\n"
expect -re  "(.*)\r\n"
puts $expect_out(1,string)
```

The source the output of that:

```
$ source <(expect test.exp)
$ echo $FOO
stackexchange
```

Answer (score 0):

```
spawn /bin/bash -c ". ./source_script.sh && ./exec_script.sh"
```